# Python open .py file in a script: save .py-file with new name

Tags: python

I want to open an existing .py file within a python-script. Then i want to save that file but with a new filename. The result should be 2 identical .py files with different names. Would be great, if somebody could explain me how that works. Thank you

Comment: This is as simple as opening the file using `with open('file1.py','r')`, and then opening another `file2.py` in write mode and writing `file1`'s contents

Comment: you can find related information here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Comment: Just check the docs or one of the many python tutorials for how to read and write files. You could search for "read write file python" or "copy file python" and have an answer in less time than it took you to write this question.

Comment: Why don't you use [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) for this task?

Answer (score 4):

```
with open("source_file", "rb") as f1:
    with open("destination_file", "wb") as f2:
        f2.write(f1.read())
```

The result is two identical files:

```
$ md5sum source_file 
65ebdbfe37cc2d221498be0745c85d37  source_file
$ md5sum destination_file 
65ebdbfe37cc2d221498be0745c85d37  destination_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're looking for.

```
with open('first_file.py', 'r') as input:
    output = open('copy_file.py', 'w')
    output.write(input.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful -

```
with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(f1.read())
```